# How to print a stack using arrays in c++

Tags: c++, stack

I have added all the required functions - e.g. push, pop and print - in my program, but am unable to print stack output on the console screen. I created three separate files containing classes, functions and the main file. I want to know that the elements I am inserting in the stack are successfully inserted therefore I need to print the updated stack.

stack.h

```
#ifndef Stack_H
#define Stack_H

using namespace std;

class Stack{
private: 
//int const capacity=50;
int stack[50];

int count;
int top;
int maxitem;

 public:  //this is where the functions go
 Stack();//constructor
 void Push(int data);
 void Pop(int delData);
 void PrintStack();
 };


#endif
```

---

stack.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "Stack.h"

using namespace std;

Stack::Stack()
{
    top=-1;
};

void Stack::Push(int data){
    top++;
    cin>>data;
    stack[top]=data;
    count++;
    cout<<"inserted succefully :"<<data<<endl;
}

void Stack::Pop(int item)
{
 if(top<0){
 cout<<"stack is empty";
            }
 else{
     item=stack[top];
     top--;

    cout<<"The deleted elememt is: "<<item<<endl;
     }
}


void Stack::PrintStack()
{
    if (top<0)
    {
        cout<<"Stack is empty ";
    }
    for(int i =top; i<0; i--)
    {
        cout<<"STACK IS "<<stack[i]<<"  "<<endl;
    }
}
```

---

main.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include "Stack.h"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    Stack R;
    int ele;
    int data;
    cout<<"enter the maximum elements in stack "<<endl;
     cin>>ele;
    cout<<endl<<"now enter the elements in stack "<<endl;


    for(int data=0; data<ele; data++){
    R.Push(data);

    R.PrintStack();
    }


    R.Pop(item);
    R.PrintStack();//stack after deletion of element


    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: How about `for (int i = 0; i < top; ++i) cout << stack[i] << endl;`

Comment: Or `for (int i = top - 1; i >= 0; --i) cout << stack[i] << endl;`

Comment: `I want to know that the elements I am inserting in the stack are successfully inserted`  Why not just use your debugger?

Comment: Where's the question?

Answer (score 1):

For example the function can be defined the following way

```
void PrintStack()
{
   for ( int i = top; i >= 0; --i ) std::cout << stack[i] << ' ';
}
```

Take into account that function Pop has no sense. At least it should be declared as

```
 void Pop(int &delData);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know that the elements I am inserting in the stack are successfully inserted therefore I need to print the updated stack.

The Stack Container is a Last In First Out container adapter giving you direct* access only to the back element (which is known as the top).  When you write your own `Stack` class, keep that in mind.  If you want to ensure your value was actually inserted, implement a `top()` function that returns the value at `stack[top]`.  Check `top()` after every `push()`.

*Note - You can write an adaptor to access the underlying container `c` in the standard implementation of `std::stack`.